# Evaluating EL expressions for HTML attributes in JSPX document

Tags: java, jsp, jspx

I working with JSPX documents in a Spring application, and I found a strange thing: EL expressions are not evaluated in HTML attributes, only in taglib attributes. Let me show an example. Given the following snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="${articles}" var="article">
  <a href="/articles/${article.id}">${article.title}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

If I have article with id 2 and title "StackOverflow example" then I get following output:

```
<a href="/articles/${article.id}">StackOverflow example</a>
```

So, the expression in a href attribute not becomes evaluated. Is it normal? I worked it around with `<jsp:element>` magic, but it would be more useful if EL evaluation could be work in HTML attributes too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web.xml has the right declaration at the top, eg:

```
<web-app
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
...
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **c:url** instead of html anchor link.See this [link](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_using_jstl.htm) to learn c:url.